# Bugzilla LDAP Server2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ldap, bugzilla

Since I upgraded my domain to Windows Server 2008, the LDAP authentication in Bugzilla is failing for certain users (invalid credentials). Is there a fix for this? I am using Bugzilla 3.0. Please advise.

Comment: Are there any log file entries, either for Bugzilla or on the Windows event log side?

Answer (score 1):

Use a network sniffer like Wireshark to make a capture of the LDAP traffic. If it is tunneled trough SSL get also the private key of the LDAP server or use a LDAP proxy. LDAP is pretty chatty and you will find easily why it denied the request.

**EDIT:**
Try to isolate the problem. Check the Windows logs. Try to connect with a different LDAP client using the same credentials as that user. Try to bind to the LDAP server using a small PHP script. You can try [phpLDAPadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Well I ran WireShark and it shows invalid credentials but my stuff and the other users are good.